# JUnit initializationError using @SpringBootTest Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, junit

I'm coding some tests using Junit 5 from the Jupiter library. When I use the @SpringBootTest annotation I get the error (Initialization error)

Full Stack Trace.

```
org.springframework.util.Assert.state(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.state(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:379) at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:312) at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:265) at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:108) at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:99) at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.(TestContextManager.java:139) at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.(TestContextManager.java:124) at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$0(ExtensionValuesStore.java:80) at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:185) at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:87) at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:91) at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespaceAwareStore.java:61) at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.getTestContextManager(SpringExtension.java:202) at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.beforeAll(SpringExtension.java:76) at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$7(ClassTestDescriptor.java:358) at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72) at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassTestDescriptor.java:358) at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.before(ClassTestDescriptor.java:197) at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.before(ClassTestDescriptor.java:74) at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:105) at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72) at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98) at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74) at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$4(NodeTestTask.java:112) at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72) at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:98) at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:74) at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220) at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188) at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202) at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181) at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:102) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:82) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:78) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35) at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24) at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32) at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93) at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source) at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:132) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35) at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24) at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:175) at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:157) at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:404) at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63) at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Suppressed: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.Assert.state(ZLjava/util/function/Supplier;)V at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:379) at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:312) at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:265) at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:108) at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:99) at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.(TestContextManager.java:139) at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.(TestContextManager.java:124) at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$0(ExtensionValuesStore.java:80) at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:185) at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.remove(ExtensionValuesStore.java:101) at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.remove(NamespaceAwareStore.java:73) at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.afterAll(SpringExtension.java:88) at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$11(ClassTestDescriptor.java:396) at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72) at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$12(ClassTestDescriptor.java:396) at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257) at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeAfterAllCallbacks(ClassTestDescriptor.java:396) at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.after(ClassTestDescriptor.java:221) at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.after(ClassTestDescriptor.java:74) at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:118) at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72) at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:118) ... 44 more
```

My test class:

```
package cl.scotiabank.ms.signers.service;

    imports...
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = StartApplication.class, webEnvironment =SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class ActionWaysServiceTest {

@InjectMocks
ActionWaysService actionWaysService;

/*
@Autowired
ActionWaysService actionWaysService;
*/



@BeforeEach
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
void getActionWaysBySigner() {
    ResponseEntity<ServicesResponse> result = actionWaysService.getActionWaysBySigner(MockFactory.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_VALUE, MockFactory.KEY_USER, MockFactory.KEY_ENTERPRISE);
    Assertions.assertNull(result);
}
}
```

Dependencies:

```
 dependencies {
    implementation library.spring_boot
    implementation library.sprint_boot_actuator
    implementation library.rxjava2
    implementation library.gson
    implementation library.project_lombok
    implementation files("${rootPath}/libs/client-signers-0.2.8.jar")
    implementation files("${rootPath}/libs/admcommons-0.9.3.jar")
    implementation files("${rootPath}/libs/enterprise-clients-1.11.2.jar")
    implementation files("${rootPath}/libs/datapower-client-1.7.jar")

    annotationProcessor library.lombok_processor

    /**
     * Testing implementation
     */
    testImplementation library.spring_starter_test
    testImplementation library.junit_jupiter

    /**
     * Mockito implementation
     */
    testImplementation library.mockito_junit_jupiter
    testImplementation library.mockito_core

    testImplementation library.byte_buddy
    testImplementation library.wiremock_standalone
}
```

Libraries:

```
 library = [
    /* spring */
    spring_boot                           : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web",
    sprint_boot_actuator                  : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator",

    spring_cloud_starter_netflix_hystrix  : "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix",
    spring_cloud_starter_netflix_dashboard: "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard",
    rxjava2                               : "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.1",
    gson                                  : "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5",
    spring_oxm                            : "org.springframework:spring-oxm:3.0.4.RELEASE",
    spring_ws_core                        : "org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:3.0.7.RELEASE",

    project_lombok                        : "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4",
    lombok_processor                      : "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4",

    /* testing */
    spring_starter_test                   : "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test",
    junit_jupiter                         : "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.2",

    mockito_junit_jupiter                 : "org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:2.24.0",
    mockito_core                          : "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.24.0",
    byte_buddy                            : "net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.9.10",
    wiremock_standalone                   : "com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock:2.18.0"
]
```

I'm Using SpringBoot 2.1.4

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an older version of a Spring library in the dependency graph. This can happen through transitive dependencies if you don't use constraints to minimize the risk of incompatibilities. You can check if this is the case through `gradle dependencies --configuration testRuntimeClasspath` and check if the version of the Spring libraries are as you expect.

If not, you can fix it using the the Spring Boot BOM like this:

```
implementation platform('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.1.4') // Need to match the version of the Spring Boot plugin
```

Alternatively, you can also use the Spring Dependency Management plugin like this:

```
plugins {
  id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.8.RELEASE"
}
```

Only use one of these approaches - not both.

Even if this is not the problem, I consider it good practice to use the BOM in any case.

You didn't show it, but just in case you missed it: to use the JUnit 5 APIs, you need to instruct Gradle to use it like this:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```